# Webstorm: Stop and rerun, enable popup

Tags: webstorm

Since some days I am having strange problems related to JetBrains Webstorm. I have set some breakpoints in index.html (some javascript functions defined in script tags), but when I debug an application, I see app stopping on different points, or pretending to stop on lines not existing in file index.html (line 272, in a file with 270 lines).
Who knows what is happening? invalidating cache and restarting don't have any effects. The only things to do is to remove all breakpoints and set them again: for the first time, it works as expected, but on next times it doesn't work at all.

It seems that this happens after I made a little mistake. When you rerun a app already running, usually Webstorm ask you if you want to stop currently running instance and starts new one; I was wrong, and I checked "Don't ask again" checkbox, so this popup doesn't show anymore. How can I restore original behaviour?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To restore original behavior (showing a dialog on restarting current debug session), remove `<property name="restartRequiresConfirmation" value="false" />` key from .idea/workspace.xml.

the breakpoints issue is likely caused by having several embedded script tags in .html - see [WEB-14466](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14466)